# How to set multiple CSS style properties in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to make my input field have a black background and white text, but I can't find any documentation for the possible values `input.style()` can take. I'm currently trying:

```js
input.style('background-color', "#121212", 'color', "#EEE")
```

The background color works, but the text color doesn't. I followed the same syntax the reference uses so I'm not sure why.

Also if anyone could point me to where in the documentation it lists all the possible arguments for `.style()` it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [p5 `style()` function](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/style) takes only two arguments: the property name and the value.  You are trying to set additional properties by adding more arguments, which you cannot do.  You need to break this up into two lines and set each property individually.

```
input.style('background-color', "#121212")
input.style('color', "#EEE")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using two separate calls to `.style`, one for each property you want to set:

```js
function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  const inp = createElement("input");
  inp.value("hello world");

  inp.style("background", "yellow");
  inp.style("color", "green");
  
  // or chained:
  inp
    .style("background", "yellow")
    .style("color", "green");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

I prefer to style with classes and a CSS stylesheet, separating presentation and behavior and making it easier to apply the style to many elements without writing a ton of repetitive JS:

```js
function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  const inp = createElement("input");
  inp.class("ugly");
  inp.value("hello world");
}
```

```css
.ugly {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Note also, with respect to naming an input `input`:

> p5.js says: you have used a p5.js reserved function "input" make sure you change the function name to something else.